# Algebraic way to determine the bounds for double/triple integrals.

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

So I was wondering, if we are given, say a double integral, where the bounds are in terms of x,y. Are there any algebraic ways to find what the bounds are for polar coordinates? I always just draw the region and then find the bounds from that, but I assume you can simply substitute the polar coordinates into the bounds and solve for $r$?What about $\theta$?

Comment: Do you have a simple example?

Comment: @mvw Say the integral with bounds $y=\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}$ and $y=0$ and $x=0$ to $x=1$